# Error loading image in SpriteKit Hello World

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've created a new "game" xcode project, and I'm trying to do a really simple "Hello World" where I display an image on the screen.

My image does not load. Error: `SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "img/flappy1.png"`

The code is an exact copy of a tutorial where it works. Am I forgetting something?

**My code:**

[image]

**My image:**

[image]

**When I run the app:**

[image]

Comment: I have to compliment you on your extremely detailed question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try "flappy1.png" instead of "img/flappy1.png".**

The things that look like folders in Xcode's organizer are not actually folders on disk, but instead "groups" that exist only within Xcode.

In addition to this, when an asset is added to a project in Xcode, the project stores a path to the asset, and it can be loaded without an absolute path.

So:

```
var birdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "flappy1.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar error message would occur if you have two targets (iOS, macOS for example) the "Target Membership" was not set to include both for the Assets.